# HTML form name replaced with wrong symbols

Tags: html, forms

I have the following form

```
<form name="input" action="http://testdomain.com/search/?" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=205499&wpv_post_search=">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="">
</form>
```

However the actual URL displays the following search query:

```
/search/?%3Fwpv_paged_preload_reach%3D1%26wpv_view_count%3D1%26wpv_post_id%3D205499%26wpv_post_search%3D=test
```

It seems that special symbols such as `?` and `=` are getting replaced with special Encoding characters.

My question is, how do I get the form to not switch my special symbols with the encoding characters?

Thanks

Comment: The reason they're getting replaced is so that the link functions properly.

Comment: If you want to send extra data use hidden `input`s.

Comment: I just want to submit the exact URL as shown in the name attribute. I don't want my special symbols to get replaced, because it doesn't work afterwards

Comment: Why on earth would you have that whole thing as the name of the input? The name should be something simple, like "search" which you will use in your controller to pass and/or manipulate the data.

Comment: I didn't write the PHP logic part of the process, I'm only writing the front part of the site. So when a user submits a search from the frontend form I created, the whole URL needs to be passed or the PHP doesn't process it correctly....

Comment: that's not a valid name for an input field. Stop writing invalid HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` of an `input` element controls the name of one field. The browser doesn’t blindly mash it and its value together and send that to the server. For a GET request, you can include each one as a hidden field:

```
<form name="input" action="http://testdomain.com/search/" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="wpv_paged_preload_reach" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="wpv_view_count" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="wpv_post_id" value="205499" />
    <input type="text" name="wpv_post_search" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a tone, this approach worked great. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes  :)